using lombok @Delegate with abstract classes
I want to create a delegate around a class for hot swapping.
I tried this:
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
public class DelegateClock extends Clock {

  @Delegate
  private Clock clock;
}

Unfortunately, I am getting "Class DelegateClock must either be declared abstract, or implement abstract methods getZone"
When I remove the extends Clock part, the class actually gets generated, and has the getZone method, however not having it extend Clock defeats the purpose.
Edit: don't know if this is relevent, but this is under test-classes

Did you try actually compiling the code? It compiles perfectly for me. IntelliJ gives you that error, but that's just IntelliJ being stupid.
